# What factors to consider when buying a travel bottle warmer?

Tags: bottle-feeding

What factors should I consider when looking into Travel bottle warmers.  I currently travel with a regular sized one I use at home, but it gets too annoying having to carry it around.

Comment: Be aware that we don't do _shopping recommendations_ on this site. But it's perfectly fine to ask for _what factors to consider when wanting to buy (insert product type here)._  The reason is that an answer with a specific product will be outdated in a year when it's not available anymore (indeed it might not be available in your region at all), but we aim for Q&A's with lasting value.

Comment: Ok,  it's not really tied to a specific brand, it's more of a question like factors to consider when wanting to buy a bottle warmer.

Comment: Then you're fine! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factors that are important to you! But seriously:

Obviously as a bottle warmer it needs to warm milk. Since it's warming it for a baby, it needs to not make the milk too hot, which requires either a timer or sensor. Assuming you aren't carrying around a generator, it needs a power source, probably a battery. You explicitly mention weight, so that's a factor to consider. If you have finite monetary resources, the price has to be considered. Consider where you'll be using it; an unstable warmer that requires a perfectly flat surface may not be practical when out and about. You also mention comfort when carrying, that implies the need of an ergonomic handle or gripping surface.

---

My advice when buying any product is to write its function, a verb, and the types of matter and energy it interacts with, nouns. Then establish requirements and preferences for how these nouns go through the verb process. I could continue walking you through this exercise as above, but no one has a better idea of your needs than you.

I suppose this is basically the modern design engineering process for idea generation applied to evaluation, but it's proven in the other capacity and should work well here too.